# Why does simpletest report a missing schema for my custom module?

Tags: 8, configuration

My custom module is working as expected with the following settings, config and config export. But when I try to run tests, I get the following error. I'm not sure what is wrong.

> Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\SchemaIncompleteException: Schema errors for riddler.settings with the following errors: riddler.settings:riddles missing schema in Drupal\Core\Config\Testing\ConfigSchemaChecker->onConfigSave() (line 102 of /var/www/sb/sboss/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Testing/ConfigSchemaChecker.php).

```
# settings.yml
riddles:
 -
    question: 'Do you really hate Spam?'
    response: 'Yes!'
langcode: en
 
 
--------------------------------
 
 
#schema
riddler.settings:
  type: config_object
  riddles:
      question:
        type: label
        label: 'Question'
      response:
        type: label
        label: 'Response'
 
 
#config export
 
riddles:
 -
    question: 'Do you really hate Spam?'
    response: Yes!
  -
    question: 'What''s your favorite primary color?'
    response: 'blue, yellow, red'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked.

```
riddler.settings:
  type: config_object
  mapping:
    riddles:
      type: sequence
      sequence:
        type: mapping
        mapping:
          question:
            type: label
            label: 'Question'
          response:
            type: label
            label: 'Response'
```

Thanks to chx for getting this most of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors. You missed a type for riddles and tried to define a mapping immediately under, but riddles is a sequence and each element in the sequence is that mapping. This is probably what you wanted.

```yaml
riddler.settings:
  type: config_object
  mapping:
    riddles:
      type: sequence
      sequence:
        type: mapping
          question:
            type: label
            label: 'Question'
          response:
            type: label
            label: 'Response'
```